# Apply approxfun in a nested list in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a nested list as in the example below:

```
 # Nested list
    df <- list(
  list(
    Mean = seq(0,100, length.out = 1500),
    MVC = seq(0,100, length.out = 1400),
    z = seq(0,700, length.out = 1450)),
  list(
    Mean = seq(0,100, length.out = 1480),
    MVC = seq(0,100, length.out = 1460),
    z = seq(200,900, length.out = 1490)
  )
)
```

And I need to interpolate **ONLY** the `Mean` and `MVC` in the two lists, so that they are all the same length. In this case, I need to interpolate all of them to the max length (1500).

I am trying to do that using

```
lapply(df, function(x) approxfun(x)(seq(0,100,length.out = newlength)))
```

where `newlength` is equal to 1500. However, this is not working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to be more specific in your `approxfun`. Right now you pare passing in a whole data.frame. Try doing this for one data.frame correctly. Translating it to a list will be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rapply` , since your data is lists of lists:

```
rapply(df, function(x) approxfun(x)(seq(0,100,length.out = newlength)) , how='list')
```

The above worked well on my system, since the result is too large to paste, I am unable to paste it.